# How do I remove the highlighted line of code with a hex editor?

Tags: windows, hex-editors

As the title reads, I am attempting to remove the following line of code with CFF Explorer since the image it refers to has been lost and I would rather nothing be displayed than a broken image icon.

Image :

[image: Screenshot of assembly code]

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to "remove" the using call too, hence overwrite with [NOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)), no-operation codes for the code after the label above till before the xor eax,eax.

NOP is the byte 90 in X86, so fill in all bytes with 90.

In this way jump addresses can remain untouched. If the label were not there,
maybe for some jump into that point, it would suffice to change the conditional jump, `jg`= jump on greater, to an absolute jump.

I hope not calling the subroutine has no other effect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm new to this but willing to learn.

How do I go about finding and overwriting that code with NOP code using a hex editor?

I’m able to find what I need within the editor but do not know how to go about making changes with it. From what I have read there is a formula to find the bytes I’m looking for but not sure I completely understand what values I need.

Comment: Work on a copy of course. Try out hex editing on a tiny text file first. There are both editors with editing and with just a hex dump. Experiment. Theoretically you could also note the start position and write a tiny application patching those bytes.